# Show that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|x_n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, limsup-and-liminf, weak-convergence

Let $(x_n)$ be weakly convergent, but not norm convergent, sequence from a Banach space. Show that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|x_n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

Any help?

Comment: What do you know about weakly convergent sequences?

Comment: $\forall \phi \in X' : |\phi((x_n))-\phi(x)| \rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $x\in X$. And if norm limit exists it is the same as limit in weak covnergence.

Comment: I was aiming for a property involving the norm that weakly convergent sequences have. They are xyz, and therefore $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \lVert x_n\rVert^{1/n} \leqslant 1$. Then you need to see why under the additional hypothesis here it cannot be smaller than $1$.

Comment: could you explain "xyz"?

Comment: That's the property I was aiming at. What properties have weakly convergent sequences? Which may be helpful?

Comment: $\Vert x\Vert \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \Vert x_n \Vert $ if $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$?

Comment: No, that wasn't it. That inequality only gives a lower bound on $\limsup \lVert x_n\rVert^{1/n}$, but we want an upper bound.

Comment: I can't think of anything else;/

Comment: It starts "bo....."

Comment: I still have no idea. Sorry

Comment: Weakly convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: Norm bounded yes?

Comment: Yes. Being weakly convergent implies weakly bounded, and that is equivalent to being norm bounded. The equivalence of weak boundedness and norm-boundedness is an important theorem by Mackey.

Comment: I'm stupid. I still cant figure out the solution, although I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A weakly convergent sequence in a normed vector space is norm-bounded. So there is an $M \in [0,\infty)$ such that we have $\lVert x_n\rVert \leqslant M$ for all $n$. Then $\lVert x_n\rVert^{1/n} \leqslant M^{1/n} \to 1$, whence

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \lVert x_n\rVert^{1/n} \leqslant 1.$$

Now it remains to show the inequality in the other direction,

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \lVert x_n\rVert^{1/n} \geqslant 1$$

for a sequence that is not norm-convergent. For example by showing the contrapositive, if the $\limsup$ is smaller than $1$, then the sequence is norm-convergent.